Is ValueQ still leaky?
Several questions have asked about how to implement a version of ValueQ that doesn't leak evaluation.
Is this still problematic after version 12.1? The obvious things I know to check seem to indicate that its safe now,
n = 0;
ClearAll[f, g];
f[x_] := Print["inside f"];
g[x_] := x + (++n);
{ValueQ[f[1]], ValueQ[g[2]]}(*no printing*)
n(*0, n did not update*)
{ValueQ[f[1], Method -> "Legacy"],ValueQ[g[2], Method -> "Legacy"]}(*prints "inside f"*)
n(*1, n did update*)

But I am concerned there might be more subtle leaks I don't see.
Additionally, supposing that it is safe now, should I (someone relatively new to SE) follow the advice here and post new answers on those questions I linked to above? Or should someone with more MMA/SE knowledge/reputation edit questions to point out the change after 12.1?

According to GeneralUtilitiesPrintDefinitions, the contemporary version of ValueQ by default works by internally calling the kernel function SystemPrivate`HasAnyEvaluationsQ. Since this is a kernel function not defined at top level, without the source code it's hard to say definitively whether its completely safe in all cases. However, as far as I can tell, it works as intended without any evaluation leaks.

I'm not sure how to correctly format my comment, since it apparently requires escaping the backticks...

@GlennWelch, if the code contains a backtick, you have to use triple backticks (```) at the beginning and the end of the code part.

If you're too shy to post answers to those questions, consider posting them as community wiki :) .

I think new answers to those questions using the updated ValueQ would be welcome.

I can confirm that ValueQ is much safer since 12.2.  Since it is HoldAll and not HoldAllComplete, there are a few cases to still be careful of:
In[1]:= ValueQ[Sequence[]]

During evaluation of In[1]:= ValueQ::argx: ValueQ called with 0 arguments; 1 argument is expected.

Out[1]= ValueQ[]

In[2]:= ValueQ[foo] ^= foo

Out[2]= foo

In[3]:= ValueQ[foo]

Out[3]= foo

Aside from Sequence objects being flattened and upvalues that might rewrite the ValueQ expression itself, no other evaluation of the expression is allowed now by default.  For symbols it checks whether the symbol has ownvalues, and for general expressions it checks whether any symbol in the expression has any definitions.
By the way, here is how it used to work:
If the argument is a symbol, check if applying its ownvalues would perform a non-trivial replacement.  This doesn't leak evaluation of the right-hand side, but still leaks evaluation of any conditions:
In[4]:= x := Echo[42]

In[5]:= ValueQ[x, Method -> "Legacy"]

Out[5]= True

In[6]:= y /; Echo[True] := y

In[7]:= ValueQ[y, Method -> "Legacy"]

True

Out[7]= False

For any other expression it just did a trial evaluation:
In[8]:= f[x_] := Echo[x]

In[9]:= ValueQ[f[42], Method -> "Legacy"]

42

Out[9]= True

